# How to find a factor $x-4$ of a polynomial function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$g(x)=x^4+0.5x^3-11.5x^2-2x+30$

is $x-4$ a factor of $g(x)$ ?

I can't figure out how to factor this out to see if $x-4$ is a factor

Comment: If you plug in x=4 and the result is y=0, then x-4 is a factor. Google how to factor polynomials.

Comment: You could also use synthetic division. If the remainder is 0, it is a factor.

Answer (score 1):

$(X-4)$ is a factor of $g$ if and only if $g(4)=0$; here we have $g(4)=126\neq 0$, so $(X-4)$ is not a factor of $g$.

Answer (score 1):

$x-4$ is a factor of $g(x)$ if and only if $g(4)=0$, in other words 4 is a root of $g$. Since
$$g(4) = 4^4 + 0.5\cdot 4^3 - 11.5\cdot 4^2 - 2\cdot 4 + 30 = 126$$

$x-4$ is not a factor of $g(x)$.